# Django: Saving new object with form and inline formset (transaction managment)

Tags: django, transactions, inline-formset

I have a form in which I creates a new "parent" object, exactly one child object of type A and n child objects of type B (n can also be 0). I do this with a form and and two inlineformsets.

I have set in settings `'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': True`.

I'm using a function based view. The code for saving the data is like this:

```
if form.is_valid():      
    parent = form.save();
    formsetA = AFormset(request.POST, instance=parent)
    formsetB = BFormset(request.POST, instance=parente)
    if formsetA.is_valid():
        # save first form in inline formset (there always only is one)
        # and then assign meta data
        a = formset[0].save()
        if formsetB.is_valid():
            for b in formsetB:
                if b.is_valid():
                    b.save()
```

Check if parent is valid, save it and set it as instance of the inline formsets. Then check the inline formsets. If a form is not valid I redirect back to the form. No exception.

Issue is that if a inlineformset is invalid, it returns to the form but the parent was already saved and transaction is not rolled back. If I roll back the transaction manually just before redirecting back to the form I get an exception:

```
An error occurred in the current transaction. You can't execute queries until the end of the 'atomic' block.
```

I assume I can't manually rollback inside atomic block?

My main question is how I should handle this situation correctly, eg. saving parent and child at once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What solved the immediated issue is to not commit on parent form save and then first check formsets for validity before committing the parent:

```
if form.is_valid():      
    parent = form.save(commit=False);
    formsetA = AFormset(request.POST, instance=parent)
    formsetB = BFormset(request.POST, instance=parente)
    if formsetA.is_valid() and formsetB.is_valid():
        #formsets are valid, parent can be saved
        # this assumes if formset is valid, all contained forms are too
        parent.save()
        a = formset[0].save()
        for b in formsetB:                    
            b.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found, that I had the same names of fields in different models so saving went wrong! After renaming all worked